# What Are These Empty Directories With Unknown Strings?

Tags: windows-7

Just noticed a lot of them in Windows 7 64-bit **AppData\Local*** folder:

[image]

Anybody knows what are they and if safe to remove?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a similar question on [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/what-is-creating-the-hex-folders-hex-names-in/1560e13c-a259-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5):

> #### [What is creating the hex folders (hex names in curly braces) that are piling up in my user's appdata/local folder?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/what-is-creating-the-hex-folders-hex-names-in/1560e13c-a259-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5)
>
> The appdata/local folder for that user keeps getting new hex folder names (Long names containing Hex digits and dashes, surrounded by curly braces) created in it. […] What application(s) or OS function(s) are creating these folders? […] Are they safe to delete directly via Windows Explorer?

The answer:

> I think you'll find that at least some of these folders are created
> each time Windows Live Setup performs its twice-daily version check.
> You can compare the timestamps on the folders with the log files
> created at the same time at %localappdata%\Microsoft\WLSetup\Logs.
>
> The
> product team say (via PM) that the folders are supposed to be deleted
> when setup is finished, and if they aren't, it might be because AV
> software has a lock on them. I don't believe that.
>
> So long as they're
> empty, they can safely be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen something similar on a laptop in my household, and have deleted them without incident (after checking nothing was using them!).  If you're worried, I'd copy them into a separate folder first, just to see if there are any adverse effects, and then delete them.